# Test or measure for "stability" of dispersion in many samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, variance, dispersion

I'm looking for a way to quantify if a variable has a "stable" dispersion over many samples.

More precisely, I have approximately 1000 subjects, each with 50 observations of the variable. The mean value in every subject will be different, but I'm only interested if the measurements deviate significantly from this mean. Thus I would like to identify the number of subjects where the deviations of the variable are significantly larger than 0.

The Mann-Whitney U test on the absolute values of the deviations works only when comparing two groups, but I have 1000. Similarly, the Levene test or Brown–Forsythe test work in an ANOVA-like setting where I would be interested if *any* group differs significantly.

I see the problem that my "null" might not be properly defined, since a dispersion of 0 is highly unlikely...

What procedure would you suggest? In the end, I want to give a score to the variable of how stable the variable is over the samples, and compare it to the score of other variables. Giving the ratio of large dispersion samples sounded like a nice idea to me, but I don't know how to identify "large dispersion".

Comment: A basic idea underlying most such tests is to obtain absolute residuals within each group (usually relative to the mean or median, but any central estimate can be appropriate) and then run any suitable test to compare the *averages* of those absolute residuals.  That gives you great scope to choose an appropriate procedure for your situation and--as a bonus--usually doesn't require much coding.

Comment: I'm not sure... What can I compare  the average absolute residuals to?

Comment: To each other!  As you point out, you can't meaningfully test the hypothesis of zero dispersion, because any nonconstant group of numbers would contradict that hypothesis.  As far as I can tell, you are asking how to assess the relative variabilities of the groups so you can identify those with relatively large values: "I want to give a score to the variable of how stable the variable is over the samples, and compare it to the score of other variables."  At that point the question becomes one of identifying high "outliers" or "contamination," for which there are myriad solutions.

Comment: Ok! I was hoping there might be a test for "significant dispersion", but I guess I would need to tackle the problem without a proper test.

Comment: Would it make sense to shuffle / permute the absolute residuals among all groups to find an average residual distribution, then compare the individual groups residuals/distribution to this permutation distribution?

Comment: Yes, provided--if you're doing significance testing--that you account for the 50 multiple dependent comparisons you're making.  That's why exploiting a standard ANOVA at some stage (which handles this automatically) is attractive.

Comment: I have 1000 multiple comparisons, so yeah, i need to account for that. ANOVA with 1000 groups doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: It can make sense, but--depending on what you're doing, and why, and what a reasonable underlying probability model might be--a mixed model might be more appropriate.  Instead of estimating 1000 coefficients, it treats those 1000 values as realizations of a random value and estimates its variance.